# In "UA: When Armies Clash", how is damage dealt to solos and PCs?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, unearthed-arcana, mass-combat

I was looking over ["Unearthed Arcana: When Armies Clash"](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/unearthed-arcana-when-armies-clash), and one thing strikes me as odd.

The rules in the PDF state (on [p. 1 of the PDF](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/UA_Battlesystem.pdf)):

> A stand uses the statistics [...] of the creatures within the stand.

and (on [p. 7 of the PDF](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/UA_Battlesystem.pdf#page=7)):

> Apply damage to a stands hit point's as though it were an individual creature.

Which makes sense. Essentially, 10 soldiers with 10 hit points who each deal 5 damage can be simplified to 1 unit with 10 unit hit points that deals 5 unit damage.

However, this reasoning does not make sense when units attack solos. RAW seems to say that a unit of 10 soldiers deals exactly the same amount of damage to a solo as one soldier would.

Is there something that I am missing in the rules?

Answer (score 7):

### You're not missing anything.

Under "Attack" in the "Battle Actions" section (on [p. 4 of the PDF](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/UA_Battlesystem.pdf#page=4)), it says:

> Attacks between units work the same as in the standard combat rules, except as described here.

So in lieu of any other rules, a stand attacking a solo essentially deals a tenth of their normal damage, while a solo attacking a stand basically deals ten times their normal damage.

I can't comment on whether this was intentional, but that's the way the system functions.

Mike Mearls, the author of this UA, kind of addressed this [in a March 2015 tweet](https://twitter.com/mikemearls/status/572531949484445697) (responding to [a question](https://twitter.com/Evan_Moffatt/status/572529500057169921) about the interaction between stands and solos):

> *how do stands and solos interact? Should a solo seem just as powerful as 10 comparable CR creatures?*

> **the idea is that a solo is a notable figure who has a big effect on the battle - Aragorn or Legolas in the LOTR movies.**

Comment: I think it is intentional. The PCs are all going to be solos, so this will mitigate the "100 orc archers immediately murder you all" / "100 allied archers immediately murder the enemy general" problem.